# Force a react component to be called with one of two props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm building a react component that has two optional props. While both props are optional, I would want for at least one of them to be passed at runtime. If both props are missing then the component should fail rendering. For context, I'm using Typescript react with functional components and my props are defined as interfaces. Look at the sample code below that defines props for my autosuggest component

```
interface AutosuggestProps {
    name: string;
    placeholder: string;
    suggestions?: any[];
    onChange?: (value: string) => void;
    onSuggestionSelected: (value: object) => void;
    httpSearch?: (abortController: AbortController, query: string) => Promise<FetchResponse<any>>
}
```

The `Autosuggest` component can be used in two ways

1. The creator of the component at runtime may choose to listen to an `onChange` events then performs the search and then updates the suggestions via the `suggestions` props or
2. Let the `Autosuggest` component handle the search and update it's own state and not rely on the `suggestions` props been passed to it.

I've decleared `onChange` and `httpSearch` as optional props but I would want for at least one of them to be present else the component should fail rendering. I mean the `Autosuggest` should either be called like this

```
<Autosuggest
    name="person"
    placeholder="Find person"
    onChange={handleChange}
    suggestions={suggestions}
/>
```

Or

```
<Autosuggest
    name="person"
    placeholder="Find person"
    httpSearch={searchPerson}
/>
```

But never like this

```
<Autosuggest
    name="person"
    placeholder="Find person"
/>
```

Comment: I was wondering the same thing to be able to do `<Box light>` or `<Box dark>` instead of `<Box theme="light">`. I'm just writing that here because I think it's a much simpler example of the same problem ;-)